Depth of surface charge in conductors (electrostatic)
I am interested in the electrostatic case, not in the so called skin effect.
Assume we have a charged conductor in electrostatic equilibrium.
According to the classic theory, the charge must be located at the surface of the conductor.
But at the atomic level, is there some depth the surface charge is located into, or do the electrons (or the ions) always occupy the last atomic layer?

The depth of the surface charge of an electronic  conductor is determined by the penetration depth of an externally applied static electric field. This so-called screening length is caused by the accumulation or depletion of mobile electrons at the surface, which - depending on the polarity of the field - move towards or away from the surface until this flow is compensated by a counteracting diffusion flow leading to a stationary state with a finite thickness of the surface charge layer.
The easiest case to determine this screening length is in a semiconductor with relatively low equilibrium electron concentrations, where the electrons can be considered to be a quasi-classical gas of non-interacting charged particles in an electrostatical potential following Boltzmann statistics with the potential given by Poisson's equation. Then, small deviations of the electron density at the surface, and thus also the electric field strength, decay exponentially towards zero in the interior of the semiconductor with a characteristic length called the Debye (screening) length Wikipedia, Debye length.
In general, especially in metals, the situation is more complicated due to degenerately high electron concentrations and quantum mechanical effects. See Thomas Fermi screening Wikipedia and Lindhard Theory Wikipedia. A good overview of the screening effects in solids can be found in the textbook N. W. Ashcroft and N. D. Mermin, Solid State Physics.
Note added later: In semiconductors, also so-called surface states, electronic states at the semiconductor surface related to defects that can be occupied by electrons or holes, can shield the penetration of an electric field into the semiconductor interior. These are, indeed, localized in a surface layer of atomic distance dimension.

Thank you so many for this excellent answer, and above all for the (non trivial) links.
